# what will be the efficient way to DB size?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm converting my .xlsx data to DB using python and the output size is bigger than my expectation.

The db table I create is:

```py
def create_file():
    
    cur.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [file](
      [f_uid] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
      [f_name_key] VARCHAR(200), 
      [f_name_list] VARCHAR(1000),
      [path] VARCHAR(1000), 
      [run_start_dt] VARCHAR(200),
      [run_end_dt] VARCHAR(200),
      [protocol_file_name] VARCHAR(200),
      [sn] VARCHAR(200),
      [head_sn] VARCHAR(200),
      [version] VARCHAR(200)      
      );
    """)
    
def create well():

    cur.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [well](
      [w_uid] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      [w_no] VARCHAR(50),
      [sample_key] VARCHAR(100),
      [qa] TINYINT,
      [call] VARCHAR(50), 
      [v1] FLOAT,  
      [v2] FLOAT,
      [f_uid] INTEGER
      );
    """)
    

def create_value():

    cur.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [value](
      [v_uid] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      [w_uid] INTEGER,
      [channel] VARCHAR(50),
      [max_cycle] TINYINT,
      [end_v] FLOAT,
      [v_seq] TEXT NOT NULL
      );
    """)
```

First attempt, since v_seq in value table is a long list of floats in string but the output was about 12GB

Second attempt, separate that v_seq into FLOAT columns as much as the amount of floats existed in list and put each float value into each column, output was 9GB

Third attempt, go back to first attempt, change v_seq to BLOB and gzip the long list of floats in string, output was about 8.5GB

I cannot think any more way to reduce the output size. Can you tell me any good ideas?

Comment: How big is your xlsx file? Also, it might be easier to achieve your task in SQLite or MySQL workbench.

Comment: @Kraigolas I read 3 files types, 12kb, 33kb and 235kb each . There are 314 files in total. 235kb ones are the ones contain v_seq data

Comment: "since `v_seq` in value table is a long list of floats in string" is probably your problem then. You are 1) not properly normalizing your data. You should create a separate table that relates to `[value]` via a foreign key which stores each value in `v_seq`. Doing so would solve 2) you are overallocating space for `v_seq` by defining it as `TEXT` as opposed to storing each value in a separate table. If you are using a relational database like SQL, a list of items should be stored as rows in a table, not as a single value.

Comment: @Kraigolas atm I'm using **sqlite** to deal with Db and tables. If I understood your comment correctly, you are saying separating the v_seq into new table and store them into FLOAT for each columns will reduce the file size?

Comment: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) claims that `TEXT` holds 65,535 Bytes. I'm not sure if that is variable-sized or preallocated though (hopefully another user will point that out). Regardless though, accessing and working with values in `v_seq` will be much easier if you split it into another table, so it is well worth your time to do so, and I suspect that `TEXT` is not variable sized, so you are allocating 65 kb per row for `v_seq`. Because your database should be around 100 MB, and it has blown up to 9 GB, so this makes sense as the reason.

Comment: @Kraogolas sqlite doesn't work that way.